# Why did Bierut threaten to murder families of those who did not join him?

Tags: poland, communism

My knowledge is very small on this. Boleslaw Bierut was a Polish Communist leader who became the President of Poland after the Soviet takeover of the country, in the aftermath of WW2 as Wikipedia says.
From a family member, I came to hear that after the Second World War, men with families that refused to join the Polish United Workers' Party were murdered along with their families.

I could not find more on this subject, however my curiosity increased ever since.
What was the reason behind this?

Comment: The obvious reason is to motivate people to join the party.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace That reason works against sheep only. These ones were not sheep. Why they joined the party instead of struggle against him? 3 years ago they all struggled against Nazism.

Answer (score 2):

[Polish United Workers' Party appeared in 1948 as a join of Polish Work Party and Polish Socialist Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_Socialist_Party). All members of both ancestors automatically became members of the Polish United Workers' Party. So, the reason of the personal terror couldn't be the struggle for individual members.

Communists simply wanted socialists leaders to agree with that join. Here the terror was useful. That terror for Socialist Party was named "The Cleaning". What is funny, **they were not communists who did the dirty work, but the socialist themselves**. Communists proposed to socialists the power, socialists fell apart in two factions, one for join with Peasant Party, and the other, under the lead of [Cyrankiewicz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B3zef_Cyrankiewicz), for join with Communists. Cyrankiewicz was paid by the post of prime minister and having the power, prosecuted his own ex-comrades. He became a very strict communist. Bierut got the power in 1952, much later.

It was the well known tactics of communists - salami tactics = old good "divide and conquer".

And that method of taking families for hostages is also old and well known tactics of communists. They used it in the civil war in Russia in 1918-21 years massively. All officers in Red Army had their families taken as hostages.

As for Russia, they had more fine tactics there: who did not help them was proclaimed for a non-working person and automatically didn't get any food. What meant a death, with families, too.

Comment: The last paragraph could really use a reference.

Comment: For what? All food was distributed by the state. The state was mastered by communists. Any trade was forbidden. What fact of these need reference for you?

Comment: Any reference for your interesting story? (I mean Poland, not for Soviet Union, what happened in Soviet Union in 1918-21 is well known).

Comment: @Alex there are two references in the text. Google is enough.

Comment: @Gangnus Well, not really. Food was not *distributed* by the state directly (stamps at some periods excepted) but rather bought by people in shops. Like in other, normal and sane countries.

Comment: @Gangnus To make clear why I nitpicking about this - you might recall that I am very far from being a Soviet stooge or anything, but I like historical statements to be precise and correct. The notion that people "automatically didn't get any food" strikes me as odd. People who actively opposed the regime got killed or incarcerated (where they *were* fed *something*).

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Soviets were different. Immediately after 10/1917 revolution the enemies were shot or let go for a parole. The bolsheviks (plus left SRs and maximalists) thought that the victory of the revolution is inevitable and they needn't be cruel. After the civil war began everything was different. The target group of the oppression I told about was not some group, but the whole city population. You can't put 20 millions into prison. And the camps system didn't exist yet. And we are not talking about active opposition - they were on the other side of the civil war.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg 1. Active opposition simply was in war with Soviet. 2. These, who agreed to work for bolsheviks, got food. 3. These, who didn't work for bolsheviks didn't got food. 4. These, whose help was needed were forced to help. Officers and farmers. for officers there was the system of hostages, and for farmers the system of requisition, inherited from the former regimes. (that system was introduced in all continental Europe during the Great War AFAIK). 5. SRs and maximalists were allies and participated. Later they were annihilated or became bolsheviks.